# Missing Cookbooks with chef kitchen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Trying to setup a rails app using chef but getting Missing Cookbooks error.

**Steps to Reproduce**

```
$ chef generate app chef_rails #create new app that will hold cookbooks for rails.
$ echo "cookbook 'ruby-ng'" >> cookbooks/chef_rails/Berksfile
$ cd cookbooks/chef_rails/
$ berks install
$ berks vendor
$ cd ../../
$ vim .kitchen.yml #add `recipe[ruby-ng::default]` to runlist
$ kitchen converge
```

Which gives the following error:

> Missing Cookbooks:
>          ------------------
>          No such cookbook: ruby-ng
>
> ```
>    Expanded Run List:
>    ------------------
>    * chef_rails::default
>    * ruby-ng::default
> ```

For this, I search the existing  answers on stackoverflow & figured that if I move vendored cookbooks, chef is able to find them

```
$ mv cookbooks/chef_rails/berks-cookbooks/* cookbooks
$ ls cookbooks                                                                                        
apt             chef_rails      mingw           ruby-ng         windows
build-essential compat_resource ohai            seven_zip
$ kitchen converge #works flawlessly
$ kitchen list                                                                                       
Instance             Driver   Provisioner  Verifier  Transport  Last Action  Last Error
default-ubuntu-1404  Vagrant  ChefZero     Inspec    Ssh        Converged    <None>
```

Here are the versions, I am using:

```
$ chef --version                                                                                      
Chef Development Kit Version: 1.1.16
chef-client version: 12.17.44
delivery version: master (83358fb62c0f711c70ad5a81030a6cae4017f103)
berks version: 5.2.0
kitchen version: 1.14.2
```

**Questions**

1. I am able to fix the error but I don't understand "why" this error occurred.I think this is related to `chef_repo_path` but don't really understand it. so if can explain or point to relevant docs?
2. Should I be vendoring the cookbooks into `./cookbooks` instead of `./cookbooks/chef_rails/berks-cookbooks/`. if yes, then how do I make `berks vendor` do that?
3. After development, For uploading to github. should include the vendored cookbooks in the repo as well? Planning to use these cookbooks with Chef Server to setup server for rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a few issues: first  as @StephenKing said you need to have the `.kitchen.yml` be right next to the `Berksfile` and then you also need to run the `kitchen` command from that folder. Second, you don't need (or want) to use `berks vendor`, as Test Kitchen has its own Berkshelf support that activates automatically when you have a Berksfile in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

The `.kitchen.yml` file should be placed inside the cookbook directory.